# View SVG createad in NSData in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm updating an old app that uses UIWebView. Apple will not accept my update unless I update to WKWebView.

I get a base64 string from an API, I convert it to NSData and then Show it in the UIWebView using its `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` instance method.
On swapping over to WKWebView the app crashes with the error

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

When calling `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL`.

Is there something I am missing?

```
WKWebViewConfiguration * config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:config];

// Only Shows the Base64 string
// [webView loadHTMLString:imageString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/"]];

NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:imageString options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
//Crashes the app.
[webView loadData:imageData MIMEType:@"image/svg+xml" textEncodingName:@"base64" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/"]];
```

Comment: loadData:MIMEType:characterEncodingName:baseURL:

Comment: Unfortunate that method is only available on iOS 13. I need to support back to at least 10.